# Get a (Android.Graphics) Path of a String

Tags: android, canvas, fonts, xamarin.android

I cannot find any way to retrieve a Path object representing a string. Does it exist? A list of the necessary points would be enough, but I guess, internally, a path is used.

For example in GDI+ there is:

```
GraphicsPath p = new GraphicsPath(); 
p.AddString("string");
```

From there any point of the "drawn string" can be accessed and modified.

PS: I do not mean drawing a text along a path.

Comment: Do you mean for example.. `R.string.myString`?

Comment: No no no. I am drawing in a Canvas. Like with Canvas.DrawPath(). I want to get a path object representing the letters which will be drawn

Comment: To be totally transparent with that is what I want to achieve: http://www.planetclegg.com/projects/WarpingTextToSplines.html

Yes, like DrawTextOnPath. (But I want to do it manually).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've spent quite a long time solving this problem (to draw vectorized text in OpenGL) and had to dig deep into libSkia sources. And it turned out pretty simple:

Indeed, canvas uses paths internally and it converts text to vector paths using SkPaint's `getTextPath()` method. Which is, luckily, exposed at Java side in public API as `android.graphics.Paint.getTextPath()`. After that, you can read Path back with `android.graphics.PathMeasure`.

Unfortunately, you can't read exact drawing commands, but you can sample the curve pretty closely using something like bisection.